# assigning ASCII values to variables in bison

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I want my parser to handle case like:

```
a='A'; // a should be set with ASCII(A) i.e 65
```

My token declaration looks like :

```
%union {
  double dval;
  char *symbol;
}

%token <symbol> SYMBOL_NAME
%token <dval> NUMBER
%token BINARY
%token OCTAL
%token DECIMAL
%token HEXADECIMAL
%token UNSIGNED
%token <symbol>CHAR
%token SHORT
%token INT
%token LONG
```

my statement declaration looks like:

```
statement:      ';'
|       expression             { setp($1); print_universal_base($1, 0); }
|       expression BINARY      { setp($1); print_universal_base($1, 2); }
|       expression OCTAL       { setp($1); print_universal_base($1, 8); }
|       expression DECIMAL     { setp($1); print_universal_base($1, 10); }
|       expression HEXADECIMAL { setp($1); print_universal_base($1, 16); }
```

my expression declaration looks like this:

```
expression:     expression ',' expression { $$ = $3; }
|       SYMBOL_NAME '=' expression { if(assign_value($1, $3, &$$)) YYABORT; }
|       NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
|       '\'' CHAR '\'' { if(set_ASCII($2, &$$)) YYABORT; }
```

shouldn't

```
'\'' CHAR '\'' { if(set_ASCII($2, &$$)) YYABORT; }
```

handle my case?
as I see that when I input like

```
a='A';
```

set_ASCII() is not being called. what is incorrect here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is incorrect here?

The answer almost certainly lies in the flex side of your parser: It is never returning a `CHAR` token.

You haven't shown us the flex side of your parser, but how are you making flex distinguish between a `SYMBOL_NAME` and a `CHAR`? Typically the code that detects a `<single_quote> <char> <single_quote>` sequence is implemented in flex, not bison. The `<char>` is stored in the union and the return value `CHAR`. On the bison side, change your `'\'' CHAR '\''` pattern to `CHAR`.

Alternatively, just change your `'\'' CHAR '\''` pattern to `'\'' SYMBOL_NAME '\''`.